# Move Data from Blob to SQL Database

Tags: mysql, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, azure-sql-database

I am currently in the process of moving my sensor reading data from my Azure Blob storage into a SQL database. I have multiple .csv files and in those files I have various columns that holds the date ( in the format: 25/4/2017), time, sensor_location and sensor_readings. 
My question; If I want to store the data according to their respective columns using Logic App, what step should I take? and how do I push the second file data into the row after the first file data? Thanks

Comment: Check out Azure Data Factory - it's an Azure native service that can copy data between various sources and transform it to your liking.

Comment: Thanks @TomaszTuczapski. But I don't know how to tell ADF to copy modified/ newly added data only into the SQL DB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to either write a script, (any high level language which has support or extensions for mysql will do, python, php, nodejs, etc) to import your data or you can use a mysql client like sequelpro https://www.sequelpro.com/ which imports csv files.

Here is a link as to how to insert data into mysql with php:
http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php
You can read the csv file with:

```
$contents = file_get_contents('filename.csv');
$lines = explode("\n", $contents);
foreach($lines as $line) { ... 
// insert all rows to mysql here
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion mate. But I don't think I can use PHP on Azure platform